MySQL float does not work for comma-separated decimal values
I have a text file full of comma separated decimal numbers.
When loading the data into a table using
LOAD DATA INFILE ...

it truncates each and every one of them at the comma, and only saves their integer part.
E.g. the number 4,5 is put into the column as 4.
It also returns this note for every row where it happened:
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'decimal_one' at row 14

I know that floats use a period and not a comma, but is there an easy way to work around this?
I am using MySQL in phpMyAdmin via xampp.

In MySQL, the decimal point is period, not comma. You'll need to replace the comma with period, either in the file or in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement.
